# Confusion regarding cross product formula

Tags: geometry, cross-product

I understand that the cross product formula is

$$\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B} =\left\|\mathbf{A} \right\|\left\|\mathbf{B} \right\|\sin(\theta)\ \mathbf{n},$$

where $\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane containing $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ in the direction given by the right-hand rule.

I started doing the following exercise from chapter **1.1.2 Vector Algebra: Component Form** of *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, fourth edition, by David J. Griffiths:

> **Example 1.2.** Find the angle between the face diagonals of a cube

I begin by using a cube of side $1$, as shown here in the textbook:

> [image]

Let $\mathbf{A} = (0, 1, 1)$ and $\mathbf{B} = (1, 0, 1)$.

Then the cross product formula gives us that

$$(1, 1, -1) = (\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}) \sin(\theta) \mathbf{n}.$$

So we need to solve for $\theta$, which means I need to deduce $\mathbf{n}$ first, right?

But then I remember: Isn't $\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}$ itself supposed to be the "normal/perpendicular vector" to the plane in which $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ lie? So, in that case, how does the formula $\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B} =\left\|\mathbf{A} \right\|\left\|\mathbf{B} \right\|\sin(\theta)\ \mathbf{n}$ make sense? And, furthermore, how do we now find $\mathbf{n}$ in $(1, 1, -1) = (\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2}) \sin(\theta) \mathbf{n}$? This is odd, because the cross product formula is actually often written as $\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B} =\left\|\mathbf{A} \right\|\left\|\mathbf{B} \right\|\sin(\theta)$ (with the absence of $\mathbf{n}$), no? As you can see, I became very confused.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify my confusion/thoughts here.

Comment: "which means I need to deduce $n$ first" -- no, just take absolute value of both sides, $||n||=1$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Please elaborate.

Comment: Compute $\mathbf A\times\mathbf B$.  The result will be a vector whose magnitude is $||\mathbf A|| \,||\mathbf B||\sin\theta$ and whose unit direction is $\mathbf n$.  Do you know how to find a unit vector $(\mathbf n)$ in the direction $(1,1,-1)$?  Note that $\mathbf A\times\mathbf B=||\mathbf A||\;||\mathbf B||\sin\theta$ does not make any sense, because you can't equate a vector with a scalar; you would have to say $||\mathbf A\times\mathbf B||=...$

Comment: my comment above reminds me of a math [joke](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/4l3b5m/what_do_you_get_if_you_cross_a_mosquito_and_a/)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner What you're saying is correct. I'm not sure where I got the idea it is often written $\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B} =\left\|\mathbf{A} \right\|\left\|\mathbf{B} \right\|\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Oh, I might actually be confusing it with $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} = \left\vert \right\vert \mathbf{A} \left\vert \right\vert \left\vert \right\vert \mathbf{B} \left\vert \right\vert \cos(\theta)$? The equation for the dot product might have creeped into my mind and confused me of the form of the equation for the cross product. Thank you very much for taking the time to clarify this for me @J.W.Tanner

Comment: You're welcome, @ThePointer.  You are correct that (unlike cross product) dot product is a scalar, so that equation for dot product makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbf A=(0,1,1)$

$\mathbf B=(0,0,1)$

$\mathbf A\times\mathbf B=(1,1,-1)$

$\mathbf n=\dfrac{(1,1,-1)}{\|(1,1,-1)\|}=\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt3},\dfrac1{\sqrt3},-\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\right)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: If we have that $$\dfrac{\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}}{(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2})\mathbf{n}} = \dfrac{(1, 1, -1)}{(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2})\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt3},\dfrac1{\sqrt3},-\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\right)} = \sin(\theta),$$ then how can this make sense? One is a vector, the other is a scalar.

Comment: Just figure out $\sin\theta$ from  $\mathbf A\times\mathbf B=||\mathbf A||\;||\mathbf B||\sin\theta\, \mathbf n$, since you know all the other terms

Comment: My point is, if the equation results in $$\dfrac{\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}}{(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2})\mathbf{n}} = \dfrac{(1, 1, -1)}{(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2})\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt3},\dfrac1{\sqrt3},-\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\right)} = \sin(\theta),$$ then how can the equation be correct? The left-hand side is a vector, and the right-hand side is a scalar.

Comment: You're right that you shouldn’t equate a vector to a scalar, but you’re actually dividing vectors on both sides, getting scalars on both sides

Comment: But we cannot divide vectors, right? So how can we algebraically solve for $\theta$?

Comment: It’s better to use `\|` than `||`

Comment: We solve for $\theta$ with a vector equation (the one in my first comment above).  We equate corresponding vector components

Comment: Ok, I see. So we get $$\sin(\theta) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2},$$  $$\sin(\theta) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2},$$ $$\sin(\theta) = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2},$$ which means we get $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, @gen-z, I edited the formatting of my answer accordingly